# List in Prolog, an unknown substitution?

Tags: prolog, operators

Just a little question because I do not understand something on a program I have at one of my finals :

```
p(A, [A | _]).
p(B, [_, _ | C]) :- p(B, C).
q(D, [_, D | _]).
q(E, [_, _ | F]) :- q(E, F).
r(G, H) :- p(G, H).
r(I, J) :- q(I, J).
```

The question is to make the Tree of research of that with the purpose : r(X, [a,b,c]).

So actually, two possibilities :

- `r(G, H) :- p(G, H). (With G = X, and H = [a,b,c])`.
- `r(I, J) :- q(I, J). (With I = X, and J = [a, b, c])`.

If we take the 1st one, we have : `p(X, [a,b,c])`.

So we can use the 1st rule : `p(A, [A | _]). (With A = X)`.

But I don't understand why when I launch the SWI-Prolog, a goes into X ...

Thanks !

Comment: Why could Prolog not apply `p(X, [A|_])` to `p(X, [a,b,c])`? `X` is an unbound variable in the query.

Comment: I don't understand this part :/ 
If you have : `p(X, [a,b,c]).` and you use `p(A, [A | _]).` with substiting A with X, it means : `p(X, [X | _]).` but where is the list : `[a,b,c]` inside it ?

Comment: `[a,b,c]` is unified with `[X|_]`. The latter matches any list of length >=1.

Comment: Tree of research: Do you mean search tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Satisfying `r(X, [a,b,c])` with the first rule goes into satisfying `p(X, [a,b,c])`.

Your first rule for `p/2`, `p(A,[A|_])`, states that a goal `p(X,L)` is satisfied when `L` is a list and its first element unifies with `X`.

In your case that list is `[a,b,c]` and `X` is unified with `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply !

So : `p(B, [ _ , _ | C]) :- p(B, C).` is satisfied when L is a list, and X unifies with the list, - 2 fist characters ?

Comment: `p(B,[_,_|C]):-p(B,C).` states that `p(B,L)` can be satisfied if `p(B,C)` can be satisfied where `C` is `L` without its first two elements.

Comment: Basically, `p/2` is satisfied whenever its first argument unifies with an element on an even position in the second argument (which must be a list). Interrogating Prolog: `?- p(X,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]).` will give the following answers: `X = a ; X = c ; X = e ; X = g ; false.`.